# API with arbitrary route

Tags: azure-api-management

In Azure API Management, how can I define a single operation that listens to multiple routes? In particular, I want my operation to listen on a certain prefix e.g. /file/get/ but then accept an arbitrary number of additional route parameters so my one operation might forward requests to /file/get/layout.xml but also /file/get/shared/maps/child.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL inside my operation is working for me:

```
/get/{*path}
```